# Modifying callback function's argument(s) before calling them

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, dom-events

I have a custom object that implements a function that'll be executed later. Here's how someone would call it:

```
customObject.onSomething(function(e) {
    // do something with e
    console.log('foobar');
});
```

Here's how onSomething is getting created:

```
var CustomObject = function() {
    this.onSomething = function(callback) {
        // If the user passes in parameter(s), how can I modify them before calling?
        callback.apply(this);
    }
}
```

How can I modify the argument(s) the user passed in before performing *apply* or *call* on the function?

Comment: How would you want to modify it?

Comment: I want to set e to something that'll be meaningful to the user when the user is calling the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apply` takes a second parameter which is a list of arguments to pass to the function. `call` does the same, except it passes its own argument-list (everything after the first parameter which is used as `this`).

So, if you know which parameters you expect, you can just add them to the invoking function as the second parameter to `apply` (or as a list of parameters to `call`):

```
this.onSomething = function(arg1, arg2) {
   // reverse the first and second arguments
   callback.apply(this, [arg2, arg1]);
   // equivalent:
   callback.call(this, arg2, arg1);
};
```

If you don't know what kind of arguments to expect, but you still want to do something with them, you can do so with the builtin `arguments` pseudo-array which holds the arguments given to the current function (even when you don't declare them explicitly).

You can use this to invoke the callback with the same arguments given to the invoking function, or some transformation of them; e.g.:

```
this.onSomething = function() {
    // call callback with the same arguments we got
    callback.apply(this, arguments);

    // or, make some changes
    var newArgs = ["extra argument", arguments[1], arguments[0]];
    callback.apply(this, newArgs);
};
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! Let me ask you this: What if the user sends in an n number of args (unknown). How can I dynamically pass those back into apply?

Comment: Well, `arguments` will hold `n` items which are the arguments given to the invoking function. If you need to pass these unchanged, call `apply(this, arguments)`. If you want to change them, make a new array from the one you got (you can inspect `arguments`, check for its length, copy its elements etc.) and pass that to `apply`. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're asking for is fairly simple, see below:

```
var CustomObject = function() {
    this.onSomething = function(callback, param1, param2) {
        param1 += 4;
        param2 = 'Something about ' + param2 + ' is different...';
        callback.apply(this, [param1, param2]);
    }
}
```